# How to execute gpg command with Perl

Tags: perl

I am trying to execute the following gpg command from within Perl:

```
`gpg --yes -e -r me@mydomain.com "$backupPath\\$backupname"`;
```

However I get the following error:

```
Global symbol "@mydomain" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my @mydomain"?)
```

Obviously I need to escape the '@' symbol but don't know how. How do I execute this command in Perl?

Comment: Escape the `@` with a backslash? `... -r me\@mydomain.com ...`

Comment: Perhaps find a Perl module instead of using a shell command. I found for example [GnuPG](https://metacpan.org/pod/GnuPG)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do:

```
`gpg --yes -e -r me@mydomain.com "$backupPath\\$backupname"`;
```

perl sees the `@mydomain` part and assumes you want to interpolate the `@mydomain` array right into the string.

But since there was no `@domain` array declared, it gives you the error.

The fix is simple:  To tell perl that you want to treat `@mydomain` as a string and not as an array, simply put a backslash (`\`) before the `@`, like this:

```
`gpg --yes -e -r me\@mydomain.com "$backupPath\\$backupname"`;
```

Answer (score -1):

Backticks run process in sub shell (slower, consumes more resources) and have some issues which you should investigate.

Following code demonstrates other approach which does not spawn sub shell.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $backupPath = '/some/path/dir';
my $backupname = 'backup_name';

my $command = "gpg --yes -e -r me\@mydomain.com $backupPath/$backupname";
my @to_run = split ' ', $command;

system(@to_run);
```

- [Handling backticks in Perl](http://www.novosial.org/perl/backticks/index.html)
- [Problem with backticks in multi-threaded Perl script on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5831526/problem-with-backticks-in-multi-threaded-perl-script-on-windows)

Comment: That is interesting, I did not know that.

Comment: Don't pass just an array to system. If the array has a single element, it still invokes the shell. Instead, use `system { $array[0] } @array`.